# Is hardware handshaking not available when using a USB to RS232 adapter?

Tags: serial, rs232, flow-control

As far as I understood there is two type of hand shaking. Hardware and software. 
For hardware handshaking other pins of RS232 connectors used. 
Does that mean of we us a USB converter we cannot employ hardware flow control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if the converter supports the additional RS-232 signals. Whether a converter supports them is at the discretion of the designer of the converter.

Comment: But hardware handshake cannot be transferred through RX TX lines. Are you sure??

Comment: Yes. Because a converter may support the additional RS-232 signals. You need to examine the converter itself, and of course connect the signals if you want to use them.

Comment: Is it written on converter manuals?

Comment: If you can find one. Otherwise look at what signals it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Some usb to serial cables provide full rs232 pin out and -12v to +12v voltage. Others just provide TX and RX at TTL voltage levels. And there are ones all in between.

The IC that drives these modules often have the other signal pins, including the hardware handshaking pins, but don't break them out of the connector.

You need to shop around to find the one you need.